# Installing ngpsql to use PostgreSQL in PowerBI

Tags: npgsql

I'm trying to get data from a PostgreSQL database into PowerBI Desktop but it doesn't seem to work. I think the problem is with the installation with npgsql. When trying to setup a new database connection in PowerBI I type in the database and server, and this is the error message I get:

"Unable to connect
Details: "PostgreSQL: We were unable to find a database provider with invariant name 'Npgsql'.
This error could've been the result of provider-specific client software being required, but missing on this computer.  To download client software for this provider, visit the following site and choose the 64-bit (x64) version of, at minimum, 'Npgsql version 2.0.12': https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=282716""

I've tried going npgsql website and install the required components but I can't seem to get it working. I'm not a developer so this is a bit complicated for me. Does anyone know how to get these components installed? I very much appreciate your help!

I'm using Windows 10 on a Surface Pro 3 if this helps. And I do have Visual Studio Community installed as well.

Best,
Bruno.

Answer (score 5):

I have downloaded and tried it with version 3.6.6

1. Install npgsql
2. During the installation stage, enabled "Npgsql GAC Installation" as GAC requires Npgsql.
3. Restart the PC.

It should work now.

Comment: 3) restart PC is not necessary, its enough to close restart PowerBI

Answer (score 2):

The solution from this page helped me: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Configuring-Power-BI-Connectivity-to-PostgreSQL-Database/ba-p/12567

Select the option to install to the GAC during install of the program npgsql v3.x.x downloaded from this page https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/releases

It worked for me (although I do not know why:-)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

When you install Npgsql you should enable installation into the GAC.
Otherwise component will not be automatically detectable to other programs.