# An error happened while reading data from the provider. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: windows, postgresql, amazon-ec2, powerbi

I'm trying to connect Postgres Database on AWS EC2 instance to Microsoft PowerBI. I tried various method available on internet but its showing the above error. Although I've done this connection on AWS RDS. I installed required dependencies (GAC) and all the certificates required for PowerBI.[image]

Comment: I was also afraid of this error

Comment: have you found any solution @YashPokar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've came across the same issue, unfortunately I didn't find solution to resolve it. But I found an alternative.

You can connect PostgreSQL using ODBC Connection.

Setup ODBC for PostgreSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/

After Installation, Select ODBC Connection under "Get Data"

Select "None" under Data Source Name and 
add following statement under connection string:

```
Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)};Server=<host>;Port=5432;Database=<dbname>
```

Click "Next"

Enter Username and Password, Click Connect.
If credentials are correct, you will see list of tables available in database.

Follow this reference for detailed description:
http://niftit.com/connecting-power-bi-to-postgresql/

Comment: Thanks a lot Chirag. I was really afraid and tried loads of ways.

Comment: you might want to use "PostgreSQL Unicode" as driver, we can find other options for connection strings at https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql-odbc-driver-psqlodbc/

Answer (score 29):

Following worked for me:

`File / Options and settings / Data source settings`

then select data source

and `Edit Permissions` and uncheck `encrypt connections`

Comment: Thank you for that solution! Luckily there is some PowerBI solutions on StackOverflow since I never can get any help on the PowerBI forum

Comment: Didn't work for me. My database is a Postgres one from Heroku. I can see from the DNS that it is an AWS database though.

Answer (score 8):

Two hours wasted, so writing in full.

**Download and install postgresql ODBC driver**

```
Goto below URL
```

URL: https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/

```
Scroll down
Click on a zip file to download  (i took psqlodbc_12_00_0000-x64.zip)
Unzip file
Run the .MSI file
   Take all defaults given and install it
```

**Create ODBC data source**

Find the ODBC data source using below (I took "ODBC Data Sources (64-bit)"):

```
Windows > Start button > search for "ODBC Data Sources"
User DSN > PostgreSQL ANSI(x64) > Finish
Give details
  Data source name : PostgreSQL30                ###
  DB name *** , server, port, username, pwd
  SSL mode = disabled (default)
click on Test button
  "Connection successful" message will come, else re-check details above.
```

We now have a new User DS, with PostgreSQL30 created

**Download Power BI**

```
Windows > Start button > Microsoft Store
Search for "Power BI Desktop" > Get/Install
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-get-the-desktop#download-power-bi-desktop

**Running the Power BI**

```
Get Data (On the left)
Search for "odbc" > Select "ODBC" on right pane > Connect
  DSN > PostgreSQL30 ( --- this is same as above ### --- )
  OK

"Navigator" dialog is shown, with "Display Options"

ODBC ... PostgreSQL30
> DB name   ( --- this is same as above *** --- )
  Open the > button on left of DB name
  select the tables
  click "Load" button
```

**Done.**
You have successfully connected Power BI (PBI) to your postgres or other database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ODBC also dont validate SSL certificate, then is almost equals no encryption

Answer (score 0):

For AWS look at this case https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/The-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation/td-p/531475

For non-AWS issue you should configure SSL according to Npgsql documentation https://www.npgsql.org/doc/security.html or you can disable SSL option in postgresql.conf on postgresql server.

Answer (score 0):

adding onto @chirag sanghvi answer

You may get an error 
`ERROR: character 0xefbfbd of encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in "WIN1252"`

because your database is encoded in UTF-8

Install this driver

https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases/tag/v4.1.3

then in your connection string use the Unicode driver

Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)};Server=;Port=5432;Database=

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but at least in my case the problem was due to the fact that the certificate I was using was self-signed. Once I generated a new one with certbot/letsencrypt properly signed by a CA, Power BI didn't give me any more trouble to connect.